# Clarification on the meaning of "number of decimal places"

Tags: decimal-expansion

I've learned in school that the "number of decimal places" in a number refers to how many digits are after the decimal point.

For example, `2.5 and 100.2` have 1 decimal place, and `0.234` has 3.

But what about numbers like `56.` and `45.0`? Do numbers like that have 0 or 1 decimal places?

(Also, please correct me if I'm misunderstanding decimal places in my question)

Comment: Zero, for consistency with 2.5 and 100.2. I have never seen the notation of ending a whole number with a decimal point, however, I would just write 56 (or 56.0 to 1 d.p.)

Comment: Which is the whole point - numbers can be written to whichever precision you care. 56 = 56.000 (unless you're programming and consider them as different data types), although the first is written to the nearest whole number (0 dp if you will), the second to 3 d.p.

Comment: Tags should be changed, this question is not about number theory.

Answer (score 4):

The "number of decimal places" is not a property of the number itself, but about how it is written. So $1.$ has zero d.p. and $1.0$ has one, though they are numerically equivalent.